# Serialize Date: Swagger and Spring-MVC

Tags: java, date, spring-mvc, serialization, swagger

I'm using swagger-ui and a stub server in Java Spring-MVC generated using swagger-codegen. I have a date format somewhere and if I enter some date, it always returns me the UNIX Date Time format. I would like to have the RFC-3339 format for the date and date-time. Does anyone knows how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer..

I had to overwrite the JsonFormat since I'm returning a JSON object..

Therefore, if you have the same problem as me, use:

```
@JsonFormat(pattern="...")
Date foo;
```

Do not forget to use `import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;`